# Cannot Click Button on App

Tags: android, xml

When I launch my app, I go to one of my screens to test out my game. Though, when I go to tap on the buttons, they don't work and do not change images like I wanted them to. So after various amounts of googling and testing, I believe I came across the problem. I believe I just have my text layer on top of my button layer, causing it so the buttons cannot be clicked as they are not the top layer. My issue here is I need the text on top to change constantly. How do I make it so my text does not interfere with my buttons. 
I apologize for the big amount of code. The buttons are in the third relative layout, and the text is all in the middle.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundupg" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/upgrades"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight=".5">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state2_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state3_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state4_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state5_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="8">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/upgtext"
                    android:text="Accuracy"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:id="@+id/pricetext"
                        android:text="100"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:id="@+id/upg1cost"
                    android:background="@drawable/cookie" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                    android:text="Eh, close enough."
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/upgtext2"
                    android:text="Base Cookies"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:id="@+id/pricetext2"
                    android:text="500"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:id="@+id/upg1cost"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/upgtext2"
                    android:background="@drawable/cookie" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/bottomtext2"
                    android:text="Double the cookies? Sweet!"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/upgtext3"
                    android:text="Stopping Time"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:id="@+id/pricetext3"
                    android:text="1000"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:id="@+id/upg1cost"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/upgtext3"
                    android:background="@drawable/cookie" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/bottomtext3"
                    android:text="I save an extra second!"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/upgtext4"
                    android:text="Secret"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:id="@+id/pricetext4"
                    android:text="250 000"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:id="@+id/upg1cost"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/upgtext4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cookie" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/bottomtext4"
                    android:text="End game?!?!"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

I also included an image to help give a visual representation of my code.

[image: What the screen looks like]

As well as my selector state for those who would like to know exactly what I put in it

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_enabled="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonclick" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttongray" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```

Button is used when the user has enough cash to purchase the upgrade.

Buttongray is used when the user does not have enough cash, I do not want the button to be pressable then. The Button color just turns gray.

Buttonclick is just a highlight of Button.

I have tried interchanging both states as I thought that was the initial problem. Neither can be pressed.

Comment: How 'bout not bolding anything, unless it's for appropriate emphasis?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should be enough code to illustrate your problem, but as simply as possible.

Comment: Sorry about the bold, it's just a personal preference type thing. I just find it easier reading it like that.

Comment: Bolding everything kind of eliminates the whole point of bold...

Comment: I didn't need bold, I usually don't do this when I have to actually emphasize my writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is because you are having your TextView objects above your Button objects and they steal the click event which you intend for the Button. The easiest fix would be to set:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

for all the TextView objects that overlay Button objects.

But I would still say your coding style needs to be improved. Why not dynamically change text in code based on events that happen in run time. You can use the `setText(CharSequence text)` method for buttons to dynamically set the text they should display.

Comment: Ya, I know I need a lot of work. I will try putting that in.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working but I will keep trying at this for a bit.

Comment: I got to the point where I literally put everything as android:focusable="false" and my buttons and layouts for those buttons as android:focusable="true". I also put it on my phone incase it was my computer glitching up. I googled it and from what I read it should work, but my buttons still won't press.

Comment: Okay, I had another issue as stupid me didn't set a proper onClickListener. After I did what you said and my onClickListener I was able to properly click my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Button's attribute `android:text="TEXT_HERE"` in xml to set initial text for your button and later on with on click you can set a different text by this

`Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upgbutton);
button.setText("New_TEXT");`

you button code in XML will look like this

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text = "Accuracy"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_state2_xml"
        android:id="@+id/upgbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: I read about that, the issue was I had multiple layers of texts and images which I couldn't make work.

Comment: this layout isn't that complicated as you've made it. try using Button's attributes like `drawableleft` and `drawableright` to set drawables and text instead of implementing it on different layers.

Comment: How would I add my image and change the text on the button?

Comment: add these two in button's xml
`android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_img_file"
 android:text="Accuracy"` and in onclick method of button, use this line `button.setText("TExt_Here");`

Comment: It will take me awhile to try and redo everything that way, I will get back to you in awhile as I try this.

Comment: This is really damn embarrassing, I did not have a proper OnClickListener running... I feel so stupid I probably spent 30+ hours just on this. I tried doing what you said, but I have 3 different texts and I don't know exactly how to set it up. So i just went with my insanely inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Since each "button" is so complex, you should consider creating a custom view.

Comment: I will try to look that up.